# Spring Data findBy Enum

Tags: jpa, enums, spring-data

i met such problem and don't know how to resolve it. Problem is next:
I have next model:

```
@Entity(name="Authority")
@Table(name="AUTHORITIES")
public class Authority implements GrantedAuthority {

@Id
private long id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="authority")
private asdevelopment.action.enums.Authority authority;

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return authority.toString();
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

}


public enum Authority {

CLIENT_ROLE, ADMIN_ROLE;

}
```

i can save authority and get by ID without any problems. But as soos as i call next method in repository:

```
domain.Authority findByAuthority(enums.Authority authority);
```

i get next exceptions:

```
Hibernate: select top ? authority0_.id as id1_, authority0_.authority as authority1_ from AUTHORITIES authority0_ where authority0_.authority=?
13:48:01.125  WARN [main] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL   Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
13:48:01.125 ERROR [main] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:144 - You    have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server    version for the right syntax to use near '2 authority0_.id as id1_, authority0_.authority as authority1_ from AUTHORITIES ' at line 1
```

Answer (score 4):

`select top ? ...` is certainly not a valid query for MySQL.

Check [SQL dialect setting](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects) in your Hibernate configuration.

Comment: Ah YES, THANKS A LOT! I had HSQLDialect as a dialect!